# Amazon s3 bucket mount point getting unmounted automatically

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, s3fs

I use s3fs on aws ubuntu instance to mount s3 bucket. Following is the command I used to mount the bucket.

```
sudo fusermount -u /s3/project1
sudo s3fs -o allow_other project1 /s3/project1
```

The machines are never getting restarted. But frequently this mount detached. And while access the mount I'm getting following error.

> cannot access '/s3/project1': Transport endpoint is not connected

How to make it permanantly attached?

Comment: It is possible that s3fs has crashed; does it appear in the ps listing?  Try updating to the latest version and run s3fs in the foreground via the flag -f with debug logging if the symptoms persist.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was, to unmount and mount the dirctory. The error transport endpoint is not connected was comprehended by unmounting the s3 folder and afterward mounting once more.

Command to mount: /usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other bucketname /s3
Command to unmount: fusermount -u /s3

Comment: I already done automated unmount and remount. But this won't work in production environment. We need to make sure it's not getting detached.